# Picture appears jagged on my website

Tags: html, css

Here's how it looks on the latest Chrome. Looks the same in Opera/Firefox.

[image]

Here's the actual image I'm using on the website:

> [image]

And the actual code:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="headerarea">
            <img src="../../Content/Images/logo.png" alt="Cumavi.com - Vende tus cosas en Bolivia!" />
            <p>Los mejores anuncios de Bolivia!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="bodyarea">
            <div id="leftnavigationbar">
            </div>

            <div id="mainbody">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The actual image is not displaying

Comment: @AniDev, it is showing. But it's a white image with a transparent background. White-on-white, which is remarkably...uh, interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your options when you're exporting. I don't use Paint.NET, but if you're exporting with single-color transparency, then you're going to see jaggies. Make sure that you're exporting with a transparency option along the lines of "source image alpha".

Answer (score 0):

The image above (helpfully on white) is jagged - if it doesn't look jagged in a different browser, it's probably because you're looking at an older cached version of the image, or something similar.

In essence, the text in the image isn't anti-aliased. Mystery solved. :-)

Comment: It looks good in Paint.NET, but in browsers it's jagged. Don't know why.

Comment: Because paint.NET might lack some of the tools/abilities necessary to antialias the text in the image? If cost is an issue, try using [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I agree with middaparka: the image text has not been anti-aliased. It is possible to "blur" the edges of the text in the image so it blends in with the alpha layer: you can use GIMP for this.

Comment: @Serg - If the original image looks good, why not try saving it as a 24-bit PNG with transparency - perhaps this will overcome the issue. (Sorry I'm not familiar with Paint.NET, but hopefully this is possible.)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the picture in the standard image viewer in Windows. I bet it looks jagged there, too.

Try editing the file in GIMP or any other image editing tool than Paint.NET.